# Sort and search blocks with jquery

Tags: jquery, sorting, search

Is there some easy way to search and sort blocks. I need only basic soting script which could sort it by name or age and both ascedning or descending functions on same sorting button.i Saw plenty of table sorters but i cant find anything that could sort blocks.
PS: i tried listjs and it worked, but when i installed different wordpress plugin it stopped working (i have loaded all scripts as in previous plugin,but it still wont work)

One block looks like this: (it may look like i am not sorting blocks but lines, but with css it looks like [THIS](http://profithing.com/business/)

```
<li class="one"><a href="link"><img src="link" height="125" width="125"/>
<p class="name">name</p>
<p class="age">age</p>
<p></a></li>
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're tring to sort li tags in a ul or ol tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own script pretty easily all you need is have a `comparater` function that defines your sort criteria. for example to sort on age in descending order you can do something like following.

```
var comparater = function (a, b) {
    var result = 0;

    if ($(a).find('.age').text() > $(b).find('.age').text()) {
        result = -1;
    } else {
        result = 1;
    }

    return result; 
}      

var nodes = $('.one');
nodes.sort(comparater);
```

Her is a complete implementation ascending, descending.
http://jsfiddle.net/H77Ve/.

Comment: thas very good thank you. is there way to combine asc and desc to one button?

Comment: OK my new theme decided to hate me. this code only works in old theme :(

Comment: what could cause this problem that it works in one theme and not the other? is some libraries missing or what? i have loaded jquery 1.9.1

Comment: i thought that might be cause by missing $(document).ready(function() but that was not it

Comment: ok i finaly found it. stupid html page input of wordpress was puting <p> before every <script>